# how to compare datetimes in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I got three columns with date informations, which indicate events that need to happen in a particular order and I would like to check if for any row in the dataframe the order is incorrect.

I prepared each column with `pd.to_datetime()`

Lets say the rule should be column `a < b < c`, so I tried this:

```
count = 0
for idx, _ in df.iterrows():
    if df.loc[idx, 'a'] > df.loc[idx, 'b']:
        print(f"Invalid b in line {idx}")
        print(f"{df.loc[idx, 'a']} {df.loc[idx, 'b']}")
        drop_rows.append(idx)
        count+=1
    if df.loc[idx, 'b'] > df.loc[idx, 'c']:
        print(f"Invalid c in line {idx}") 
        drop_rows.append(idx)
        count+=1
print(f"{count} invalid rows")
```

And it works for almost all rows, but for 36 (correct) rows I still receive something like the following

```
Invalid b in line 5883 2014-03-06 00:00:00 2014-03-06 00:00:00
Invalid b in line 24442 2011-11-14 00:00:00 2011-11-14 00:00:00
```

I also changed `if df.loc[idx, 'a'] > df.loc[idx, 'b']:` by `if not df.loc[idx, 'a'] <= df.loc[idx, 'b']:` but still receiving this correct entries as wrong.

Why does python think this are not the same dates and how could I change that?

Also is there a faster way to get through the dataframe than iterrows?

Comment: Your print statement is printing values from column `a` twice: `print(f"{df.loc[idx, 'a']} {df.loc[idx, 'a']}")` - is that intentional or should it be printing values from `a` and `b`?

Comment: damn you r right, thought I only did the mistake in the minimal example, but I did it in the real code as well. many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to iterate (potentially slowly) through your DataFrame rows, you could just filter the DataFrame to all rows which meet either condition, like so:

```
abc_errors = df.loc[(df['a'] > df['b']) | (df['b'] > df['c'])]
```

Alternatively you can filter to `ab` errors and `bc` errors separately:

```
ab_errors = df.loc[(df['a'] > df['b'])] 
bc_errors = df.loc[(df['b'] > df['c'])]
```